# How to replace a value in dataframe column with series index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following dataframe

```
coupon_type     dish_id  dish_name      dish_price  dish_quantity
0  Rs 20 off       012  Chicken Biryani    65            2
1  Rs 20 off       013    Tava Pulav      125            3
2  Rs 20 off       014   Chicken Kadai    135            3
3  Rs 20 off       015    Total Meal      175            3
4  Rs 20 off       016    Dal Makhani     105            4

ratings   reviews      coupon_type user_id order_id   
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9        9              
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9        9             
3     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9        9              
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9        9                
4     blah blah blah   Rs 20 off      9        9
```

I am doing group by on dish name

```
df_dish_name = df_final.groupby('dish_name')
```

Then I am performing some ratio operations on groupby. which gives me pandas series.

```
 dish_name
 Dal Makhani    18.75
 Name: dish_quantity, dtype: float64
```

Now I want to add new string 'AP' to the corresponding dish name which is Dal Makhani..

I am doing it like this..

```
df_final['Flag'] = np.where(df_final['dish_name'].isin(dish1.index),'AP')
```

But it doesn't set the corresponding value to 'AP'.

Comment: what ratio operation do you perform exactly to obtain this result? can you give your input as well instead of copy pasting?

Comment: `dish_quantity_sold = df_dish_name.dish_quantity.sum()` and then `dish_relative_perf = (dish_quantity_sold/dish_quantity_sold.sum())*100`